# How to include Python.h for python installed in miniforge?

Tags: python, c++, g++

I'm trying to install a tensor flow module written in python that is installed inside the miniforge environment.
(I use miniforge because I'm using the m1 mac)

Below is my testing c++ code:

```cpp
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
}
```

I've tried this command to build my cpp file

```sh
g++ -arch arm64 -I/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ML/include/python3.9 -o py_port py_port.cpp
```

however I got these error

```
g++ -arch arm64 -I/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/ML/include/python3.9 -o py_port py_port.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_Py_DecodeLocale", referenced from:
      _main in py_port-b72f4b.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _main in py_port-b72f4b.o
  "_Py_SetProgramName", referenced from:
      _main in py_port-b72f4b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Link with python library and library path during compilation like this [modify accordingly]

```
g++ -I/Users/subrata/.miniconda3/include/python3.9 -L/Users/subrata/.miniconda3/lib -lpython3.9  -Wl,-rpath,/Users/subrata/.miniconda3/lib  pyTest.cpp -o py_port
```

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for the quick response, may I know what `-Wl,-rpath,/Users/subrata/.miniconda3/lib` does here?

Comment: I've searched for the gcc doc, and found the description as follows.        >> >> Wl,option
Pass option as an option to the linker.  If option contains
           commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.  You
           can use this syntax to pass an argument to the option.  For
           example, -Wl,-Map,output.map passes -Map output.map to the
           linker.  When using the GNU linker, you can also get the same
           effect with -Wl,-Map=output.map.  
<<
while I didn't find the usage like -Wl,-rpath,/Users/subrata/.miniconda3/lib

Comment: Without this you may get linking error during runtime. Either you need to add the library path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH or using rpath (as I didi)